# What is happening during the "down time" when Spark is reading in big data sets on S3?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a bunch of JSON data in AWS S3 - let's say 100k files, each around 5MB - and I'm using Spark 2.2's `DataFrameReader` to read and process them via:

`sparkSession.read.json(...)`

I've found that Spark will just sort of hang for 5 minutes or so before beginning the computation.  This can take hours for larger data sets.  When I say "hang" I mean that the terminal visualization indicating what stage the cluster is working on and how far along it is doesn't appear - as far as I can tell it is somehow in between stages.

> What is Spark doing during this period, and how can I help it go faster?

I had two ideas, but both of them appear to be wrong.

My first idea was that Spark is attempting to list all of the files that it will need to do the computation.  I tested this by actually creating a list of files offline and feeding them to Spark directly rather than using glob syntax:

`val fileList = loadFiles()
sparkSession.read.json(fileList:_*)`

This actually caused the "hanging" period to last longer!

My second idea was that Spark is using this time to create a schema for all of the data.  But I ruled this out by manually specifying a schema:

`val schema = createSchema()
sparksession.read.schema(schema).json(...)`

Here the "hanging" period was the same as before, though the computation overall was much quicker.

So I'm not really sure what's going on or how to diagnose it.  Anyone else run into this?

Comment: I can't really tell you what spark is doing, but I can say that spark has never been happy with reading many small files. If you have any way of aggregating the files into fewer but much bigger files (of say at least 500MB) beforehand, you should see a vast speed up.

Comment: @GliennieHellesSindholt Thank you for that suggestion - now that you mention it, I can think of other large datasets that I have worked with which were partitioned more efficiently, and they didn't have this problem. I remain modestly hopeful for a workaround which doesn't require restructuring the data, but maybe that's the best strategy. In your experience is there an upper limit to the file size for this purpose? Maybe it depends on the cluster?

Comment: Well, I work with S3 which has a 5GB upper limit (or at least they used to - not sure if that has been removed actually), so my files are always smaller than 5GB. However, in all of my write job, I do make sure that I store data in few but large files for this exact reason.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt I took your / Steve's advice, and it paid off significantly - using fewer but bigger files (about 2.6gb) the "down time" was eliminated and the job ran faster than before.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost of listing directory trees in S3 is very high, "partitioning". This is what you are experiencing.

Fixes

- fewer, larger files
- shallower directory tree

Comment: Thank you - this sounds plausible given the way my data is organized. However, I would have expected that feeding spark a full list of files (no globs) would save it the trouble of parsing the directory tree - in my experiments this actually made things worse. Is there some other way to cache the directory tree or something to speed up future computations? I'm doing many computations on the same data, so maybe the best strategy is to merge files together and simplify the directory structure as you suggest.

Comment: yes, merging is good, not just for listing but for scheduling: each worker will be scheduled with all or part of a single file at a time: the bigger the files, the more work each can do before it needs to talk to the driver to commit that work and request some more

Comment: +spark probably took the file list and rescanned it anyway, as it wouldn't know which were directories and which were files. one HEAD request per file.

Comment: I bit the bullet and restructured the data so that the directory tree is flat and there are 1000 files instead of close to 1 million.  It paid off: the "down time" was completely eliminated, and the various computations ran significantly faster.  So you were right on the money.  (Now to try to convince the systems team to change the way we ingest data...)